# Take input of delimited file of integers and output result

Tags: beginner, vb.net

I wanted to learn some new language so I developed a really simple vb.net "console application" (was that the right type?) that takes text input, looks at it and multiplies it *if* it's even and then reads each result into a msgbox.

- test.txt = `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`
- result should be an array `{1 4 3 8 5 12 7 16 9}`

This would be my first vb.net programming attempt

```
Module MyFirstModule
    Sub Main()
        HelloNumbers()
    End Sub

    Private Sub HelloNumbers()
        Dim inputFile As String
        inputFile = "c:\temp\test.txt"
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim readResult As String() = Split(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(inputFile))
        Dim multipliedResult As Integer()
        Dim lower As Integer = LBound(readResult)
        Dim upper As Integer = UBound(readResult)
        ReDim multipliedResult(0 To upper)
        For i = lower To upper
            multipliedResult(i) = MultiplyEvenNumbers(CInt(readResult(i)))
        Next

        For i = lower To upper
            If multipliedResult(i) Mod 2 = 0 Then
                MsgBox(readResult(i) & " was multiplied by two for " & multipliedResult(i))
            Else : MsgBox(readResult(i) & " is original")
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Function MultiplyEvenNumbers(ByVal inputNumber As Integer) As Integer
        If inputNumber Mod 2 = 0 Then inputNumber = inputNumber * 2
        MultiplyEvenNumbers = inputNumber
    End Function
End Module
```

Comment: Welcome to the Wonderful World of .NET!

Comment: I'd recommend you also add the bunch of `Imports` (and any `Option`) instructions at the top of the module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good start. You created two functions to separate parts of the logic but there is more that can be refactored. The `HalloNumbers` sub is too big and does too much. Let's try to improve.

First the path shouldn't be hardcoded inside it so we pass it as parameter:

```
Sub Main()
    HelloNumbers("c:\temp\test.txt")
End Sub
```

Now we take parts of the big `HalloNumbers` and move them into fuctions that do only one thing - we always strive for this because it's easier to maintain when you only have to care about one thing at a time (see [SRP](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/solid-part-1-the-single-responsibility-principle--net-36074)).

```
Private Sub HelloNumbers(ByVal inputFile As String)
    Dim numbers As Integer() = ReadNumbers(inputFile)
    Dim multipliedNumbers = numbers.Select(Function(number) MultiplyEvenNumbers(number))
    PrintNumbers(multipliedNumbers)
End Sub
```

So we can extract the following functions:

We need to read the numbers. They are in a file. So let's require a path and after reading them we convert each number-string into an `Integer` with linq:

```
Private Function ReadNumbers(ByVal inputFile As String) As IEnumerable(Of Integer)
    ReadNumbers = Split(File.ReadAllText(inputFile)).Select(Function(s, i) CInt(s))
End Function
```

Then we need to multiply them. This one was already there so we leave it as is.

```
Private Function MultiplyEvenNumbers(ByVal inputNumber As Integer) As Integer
    If inputNumber Mod 2 = 0 Then inputNumber = inputNumber * 2
    MultiplyEvenNumbers = inputNumber
End Function
```

Finaly you want to print the results. Let's do it in `PrintNumbers`. If you decide to write the output to the console you now just have to adjust this small function.

```
Private Sub PrintNumbers(ByVal numbers As IEnumerable(Of Integer))
    For Each number As Integer In numbers
        If number Mod 2 = 0 Then
            MsgBox(String.Format("{0} was multiplied by two for {1}", number, number / 2))
        Else : MsgBox(String.Format("{0} is original", number))
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

You undoubtedly have this line at the top of your code file:

> ```
> Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
> ```

Remove it, and your code stops compiling. Why? Because you're using VB6-like constructs that this namespace provides compatibility for.

More precisely, the `MsgBox` function. Use the [`MessageBox` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox(v=vs.110).aspx) in the `Microsoft.Windows.Forms` namespace instead, for a much more .NET-idiomatic invocation:

```
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("..."))
```

`LBound` and `UBound` will also stop compiling without the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace imported.

Arrays in VB.NET are **always** 0-based, and an array's length can be determined using its... `Length` property: that's just *one* of the awesome implications of .NET's *everything is an object*.

Therefore, instead of this:

> ```
> Dim lower As Integer = LBound(readResult)
> Dim upper As Integer = UBound(readResult)
> For i = lower To upper
> ```

You can do that:

```
For i = 0 To readResult.Length - 1
```

Also, instead of using `ReDim` to resize an array:

> ```
> Dim multipliedResult As Integer()
> ReDim multipliedResult(0 To upper)
> ```

You could use the more idiomatic `Array.Resize(ref multipliedResult, readResult.Length)`... but then, why *resize* the array when you could just declare it with the appropriate length in the first place? Or better, why even use an array, when you could use a `List(Of String)` and just `.Add` values and let the framework deal with the underlying array? =)

Now, the array itself is obtained using the `Split` function, also a courtesy of `Microsoft.VisualBasic` - the .NET-idiomatic way to *split a string* is to use the `Split` method, available on any instance of any `String` object - because yes, even a `String` is an object in .NET!

```
Dim a As String = "foo bar baz"
Dim b As String() = a.Split(new String(){Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

But you don't even need to `Split` anything, because you can `ReadAllLines` instead of `ReadAllText`, and work with a string array *directly* - add `Imports System.IO` at the top of the module, and reduce the wordiness of `System.IO.File`, too:

```
Dim readResult As String() = File.ReadAllLines(inputFile)
```

Another thing that makes your VB.NET feel like VBA/VB6 code, is how you're returning from a function:

> ```
> If inputNumber Mod 2 = 0 Then inputNumber = inputNumber * 2
> MultiplyEvenNumbers = inputNumber
> ```

In VB.NET, you use the `Return` keyword instead:

```
If inputNumber Mod 2 = 0 Then inputNumber = inputNumber * 2
Return inputNumber
```

But there's more: VB.NET has combined assignment operators, so instead of this:

> ```
> inputNumber = inputNumber * 2
> ```

You can do this:

```
inputNumber *= 2
```

So to increment by one, you can't quite do `i++` like you would in C#, but you can combine the `+` and `=` and do `i += 1` to increment, and `i -= 1` to decrement.

The `CInt` conversion function is also VB6-ish; in .NET you *convert* things, so instead of this:

> ```
> CInt(readResult(i))
> ```

You would have that:

```
Convert.ToInt32(readResult(i))
```

Although, that's just [one of many ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40764/how-should-i-cast-in-vb-net) to convert types in VB.NET.

Lastly, idiomatic .net code will always have `Option Explicit` and `Option Strict` turned on... and you can reduce the verbosity of declarations by enabling `Option Infer`, so the compiler will automatically infer the correct type, so instead of this:

```
Dim foo As String = "something"
```

You can have that:

```
Dim foo = "something"
```

And `foo` is known *at compile time* (read: it's not a dynamic/runtime thing) to be a `String`.

---

#### What about LINQ?

As mentioned above, an array is an object. But it's not just *any* object - it implements an interface called `IEnumerable`, which means the LINQ extension methods can be used to iterate it, instead of an explicit `For` loop:

```
Dim readResult = File.ReadAllLines(inputFile)
Dim multipliedResults = From line In readResults
                        Select MultiplyEvenNumbers(Convert.ToInt32(line))
```

But you'll probably want to learn a bit about *closures* and *delegates* before diving into this.

Comment: I thought there might be a lot of these - thanks! Should I remove the imported `Microsoft.VisualBasic` or was that just for illustration?

Comment: @Raystafarian yep. IMO `Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic` is *always* a sign that the code is going to be doing things the old VB6 way. I'd remove it completely and work off the other .net namespaces.

Comment: I will, I just wanted to make sure I wouldn't break anything else - I think removing it will *make* me find a way to do something that I've already done in vba. Thanks!